# 4K screen resolution support on Matlab for Ubuntu

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, screen, display, screen-resolution

I am having trouble having a proper scale factor for Matlab on Ubuntu 18.04LTS.
I have a 4K screen and I have increased the scaling factor of the OS to 1.5 but Matlab does not display the menus in the proper scaling.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MATLAB supports High DPI screens on Linux starting from R2017b.

To tune a high-DPI Linux system, you need to:

1) Set the MATLAB scale factor

2) Calibrating the system's DPI

The MATLAB scale factor affects MATLAB desktop and the size/position of windows.
The system's DPI determines the scale and font size of axes and labels.

The two tuning steps are described below:

1) To set the MATLAB scale factor to, for example, 1.5, please execute the following commands in the **MATLAB Command Window**:

```
>> s = settings;s.matlab.desktop.DisplayScaleFactor
>> s.matlab.desktop.DisplayScaleFactor.PersonalValue = 1.5
```

2) To calibrate the system's DPI to match the scale factor, please use the following **Terminal** commands:

```
~$ xdpyinfo | grep resolution
  resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
~$ xrandr --dpi 144
```

The DPI value chosen should be the resolution found with "xdpyinfo" multiplied by the MATLAB scale factor that was set. In the example, 96 × 1.5 = 144.

MATLAB must be restarted after Step 2.

I achnowledge Jim from the MathWorks Technical Support Department for sharing these instruction with me.

Comment: 2019a - I didn't need to do step 2, but a scale factor of 2.0 looked much better